# GitHub Actions Pipeline Not Triggering on Push Events Without New Commits

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v1.**
    branches:
      - master
      - develop
```

I have been using this config for GitHub Actions for quite a while and the pipeline always triggered when executing `git push` even if no new commits where pushed to GitHub.

To clarify when you make a new commit and execute `git push` a new commit would be pushed to GitHub. When you execute `git push` again no new commits would be pushed to GitHub.

For quite a while on both occasions new workflow run would be triggered.

Today I noticed that when I simply push without new commits GitHub no longer triggers a new workflow run.
Was there a new change in how GitHub triggers workflows?

Edit:
[Github Status](https://www.githubstatus.com/) also doesn't report any incidents